# Computing a p-value from 95% confidence interval

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, p-value

Is there a way to compute the p-value associated with the significance of an estimation if I know the 95% confidence interval?

Comment: Readers of this question should realize that the question arises from the need to assign a p-value to the correlation of censored variables. The questioner has identified an R package that delivers an asymmetric confidence interval around the estimate. it uses an adjusted df and uses a tanh() factor. (I had asked the questioner to post an example.) Documentation cites http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/sim.5874 but it's behind a paywall for non-academic users.

Comment: @DWin thanks for the clarification. I had not included those details in the question not to confuse people. I had thought what I am asking is applicable to any statistical analysis case independent from the specific function that I am using.

Comment: The code for the df and limits are: `df = (M - 1) * (1 + M/(BetwVar * (M + 1) * df0))^2` , and : `limits = tanh(rj.t.mean + c(-1, 1) * qt(1 - alpha/2, df) * sqrt(TotalVar))`. `M` and `rj.t.mean` are components of the object retruned by the funtion. Since I cannot see the cited paper, I'm not clear re: the relationship between `rho` (the estimate) and `rj.t.mean` (which appears to be a stand-in for rho in the limits calculation.)

Comment: The general answer to the posted question is "you can't do it from a 95% CI alone" (which I am happy to post as an answer except I bet you would want to change the question then). You can say whether the p-value is more or less than 0.05 by checking whether the hypothesized value is inside the interval, but without further information you can't say by how much.